# Keras - Image Captioning with attention mechanism

Tags: python, image-processing, keras

I have written the below code for image captioning in keras & it works fine.

```
image_model = Sequential()
image_model.add(Dense(EMBEDDING_DIM, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'))
image_model.add(RepeatVector(max_length))


lang_model = Sequential()
lang_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size,EMBEDDING_DIM , input_length=max_length))
lang_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True)))
lang_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
lang_model.add(BatchNormalization())
lang_model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(EMBEDDING_DIM)))


fin_model = Sequential()
fin_model.add(Merge([image_model, lang_model], mode='concat'))
    #model.add(Concatenate([image_model, lang_model]))
fin_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
fin_model.add(BatchNormalization())
fin_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(1000,return_sequences=False)))

fin_model.add(Dense(vocab_size))
fin_model.add(Activation('softmax'))
print ("Model created!")

fin_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But I wanted to add attention mechanism here. No need of a bidirectional lstm, just a usual LSTM  is also fine. But I don't see one useful blog that explains how to do this in keras. Since I am very new to deep learning & Keras is the only python library I know, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the answer?